# fgets and dealing with CTRL+D input

Tags: c, linux, fgets, ctrl

I am grabbing some standard input from the user and if the user presses <kbd>CTRL+D</kbd>, I want to display an error and terminate the program. I think perhaps my issue may be related to being stuck in a while loop;

```
int readInput(){
   char buff[10];
   int count = 0;
   int counter;
   printf("Enter random number: ");
   fgets(buff, 10, stdin);
   if ((int) strtol(buff, NULL, 10) == 0){
      printf("Error reading number. \n");
      return 0;   //This will get hit if the user presses CTRL+D at this input.
   }
   counter = atol(buff);
   while (count < counter){ 
      printf("Enter a label: ");
      fgets(buff, 10, stdin);
      if ((int) strtol(buff, NULL, 10) == 0){
         printf("Error reading label");
         return 0;  //This will not get hit if the user presses CTRL+D at this input, but why?
         //I've also tried assigning a variable to 0, breaking out of the loop using break; and returning the variable at the end of the function but that also does not work.

      //the rest of the while loop continues even if user hit CTRL+D
      printf("Enter Value: " );
      fgets(buff, 10, stdin);
      //..rest of while loop just gets other inputs like above
      count++;
   }

//termination happens in main, if readInput returns a 0 we call RETURN EXIT_FAILURE;
```

I don't understand why at the first input if the user presses <kbd>CTRL+D</kbd>, the program responds accordingly but the second time it completely ignores it.

Comment: The way counter is being incremented in the while loop is curious. Also, is count ever being incremented?

Comment: This is on an ubuntu machine, yes.

Comment: count is incremented in the last line, counter is the random integer the user has entered. I'm more focused on why my check to see if the user has pressed CTRL+D does not work in the while loop, but it does outside of it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On Linux, <kbd>Ctrl + D</kbd> generates `EOF`, so you need to check the return value of `fgets()` every time. When `EOF` is encountered, `fgets()` returns a null pointer

```
if (fgets(buff, 10, stdin) == NULL)
    print_error();
```

Comment: Understood, any idea as to why the first check for CTRL+D worked correctly?

Comment: because D auto initializes buffers to `\0` (in debug mode at least) and in the second test you still had the old value in `buff`

Comment: @YuHao actually any non digit character in the first place of buff will let strtol return 0 so it's a 10 in 256 chance of it not working

Comment: I thought Ctrl + D was EOT character?

Comment: @HorseSMith [Meaning in Unix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-transmission_character#Meaning_in_Unix)