# reading input with fgets(goes into endless loop)

Tags: c, linux, fgets

I have this application where it reads user input with fgets. It works fine and have no problem if I take user input while program is running. But if I feed a file say "./myprog < in.txt", it goes into infinite loop and print my custom error message that I show when user doesn't provide valid input all over the screen. It's like return key is pressed. How do I solve that problem?

This is one section of my program that's has fgets

```
while(1){
  mainMenu(&choice);
  switch(choice)
  {
     case 0: 
        return 0;

     case 1: //Add movies 
        getMovieData(&list);
        break;

     case 2:
        ....some initialization... 
        printf("Provide a name to delete : ");
        fgets(inputBuffer,sizeof(inputBuffer),stdin);
    trimWhiteSpace(inputBuffer);
        deleteMovie(&list,inputBuffer);
        break;

     case 3: //List all movies
        printMovieData(list);
        break;

     case 4: //List movies by genre
        inputBuffer[0] = '\0';
        printf(".....");
    fgets(inputBuffer,sizeof(inputBuffer),stdin);               
        trimWhiteSpace(inputBuffer);
        if(!isNum(inputBuffer,&genreChoice)){ 
           showMessage("Number Expected\n");
           break;
        }
        else if(!checkNumberValidity(&genreChoice,1,6)){
           showMessage("Choose from 1 to 7\n");
           break;
        }
        else printMoviesByGenre(list,getGenre(genreChoice-1));
        break;

  }
```

}

```
while(1){
  printf("Provide the number of movies you would like to enter: ");
  fgets(temp, sizeof(temp), stdin);
  trimWhiteSpace(temp);         
  if(!isNum(temp,&numMovie)) printf("Enter a numeric value\n");
  else if(!checkNumberValidity(&numMovie,1,MAX_MOVIES)) printf("No greater than %d\n",MAX_MOVIES);  
  else break;
```

}

Comment: This will loop until choice is 0, and choice is determined by getMenu. So maybe your problem is in getMenu?

Comment: If I terminate with zero in that text file, it has no problem. It just exit to shell at the end. If I don't then it goes into endless loop.

Comment: In that case getMenu is repeatedly setting choice to non zero and thus the prints repeating. fgets() is probably returning NULL. You could use that to return also.

Comment: As one of the answers says, you need to check fgets for NULL return value and return/exit on that.

Answer (score 1):

Check the return value of `fgets`. It returns NULL on failure. At the end of the stream, `fgets` return NULL and `feof(file)` will be != 0, indicating you reached the end of stream (EOF, end of file).

As Charlie Burns said, you must exit on end of input, so do something like this:

```
if (fgets(temp, sizeof(temp), stdin) == NULL)
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
```

... in your `while(1)` loop.

Related: [fgets and dealing with CTRL+D input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19228645/fgets-and-dealing-with-ctrld-input?rq=1)

Comment: Just to be sure, verify what happens when you hit Ctrl-D when you use your program interactively (or Ctrl-Z, <enter> on Windows), just to see if it does the printf loop you see.

Comment: I just updated my post. It's a message that I show when user doesn't provide valid input. It's like user holding enter key all the time.

Answer (score 0):

i don't think the infinite loop comes from `fgets`. But its not well declared  `fgets(inputBuffer,sizeof(inputBuffer),stdin);` second argument must be a size, size that says how much char you wanna read. Show us where is you printf that you see during the infinite loop.