# Receiving input from user in c++

Tags: c++, string, windows

I'm trying to read input from user in this way

```
std::string point;
while (std::getline(std::cin, point))
{
 // SOME CODE
}
```

I want to receive input from user until he hits CTRL+D which means EOF.
obviously in the current situation I get an error since it doesn't end when I hit CTRL+D. Any tips? Thanks!

Comment: What operating system are you on? Is it windows?

Comment: yes I'm on windows 10

Comment: Hi, you are using the wrong `EOF`, it is `Ctrl - Z`, and press enter after.

Comment: First of all they didn't eventually help him out there. So I see no reason to call duplicate. Second, Arnav, it still crashes, it enters loop even though I click ctrl -z and enter

Comment: you really want CTRL+D? what about empty string?

Comment: I was told to end read by CTRL+D, it's not that I really want.. :/

Comment: you were told by a Linux guy (which is explained here also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19228645/fgets-and-dealing-with-ctrld-input). You're using windows. You have to follow Arnav advice: ctrl+Z + return. That say, MSYS `cat` command reacts to CTRL+D. I wonder how that works...

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ I agree with you it looks very much like a duplicate, however, I have followed the duplicate question answer and CTRL+D is still not understood (running Windows may be the problem??) CTRL-Z + enter works, but it worked before. The OP wants to be able to interrupt with CTRL+D alone, which is possible since MSYS `cat` command accepts it (looking at the source, no obvious reason for that)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre As the OP tagged clion I assumed OSX. Windows and using CTRL-Z may be the problem. But the behavior is pretty identical regarding `std::cin`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I edited the tag to remove clion (cross compilation) and add windows as the OP commented.

Comment: See [Console Control Handlers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682066.aspx). Make sure to read all of it, the topic is fairly involved.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> or <kbd>F6</kbd> on an otherwise empty line is the convention for marking end-of-file for a text stream. In Unix-land, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> is the convention for sending your typed text straighaway to the program, which for an empty line sends nothing (a zero length input) which the program interprets as end-of-file. Also in Windows the interpretation is in each program, not done by Windows itself or the console subsystem or command shell, and for C and C++ it's handled by the standard library's i/o facilities.

One big difference is that in Windows the Ctrl-Z is ***data***, which you can have in e.g. a text file, while in Unix-land the “submit now!”  Ctrl-D is an ***action***, that can't occur in data read from a file.

Another big difference is that because of that, in Windows you have to press <kbd>Return</kbd> (Enter, newline) after the Ctrl+Z, while in Unix-land the Ctrl-D is it, on its own.